# RFID ME Gen2 Internet

Tags: c#, rfid, usb

i want to read out some Tags from my **MTI RFID ME Gen2 Internet** : 
http://www.mti.com.tw/rfidme/
 It´s a USB Dongle and now iwant to play with him in VS with c#. So is searched long time for the SDK and 
i find some:
http://www.bait-consulting.com/RFIDMESDK.aspx
the development-kit:
www.mti.com.tw/upfiles/e_pro_tb01346397897.pdf
here is the manual with the discription:
www.bait-consulting.com/Cutomers/MTI/UserManual%28v1.1.0.110%29.pdf
now my Problem is the implementation of the sdk, there are two .dll. i include them to my project and than i would work around the sample code which is given :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
//Declare RFID ME™ SDK
public RFIDMEDevKit.reader myReader = new RFIDMEDevKit.reader();
}
```

My VS2012 throw a exeption: in line 4 : Die Zeichenfolge wurde nicht als gültiges DateTime erkannt. FormatExeption

Also the complete Code-Examples are not running :/ 
So have somebody experience with this thema? Or some Code-Samples?

Thanks a lot :) Hope you can help me

Comment: I have worked with RFID but just with Symbol products. They have a great [code-samples](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13480&sliceId=&dialogID=442068431&stateId=1%200%20442064217) that actually runs. Please try to read first the [release notes](https://docs.symbol.com/ReleaseNotes/Release%20Notes%20-%20EMDK_M_020605_UP2C.htm) in order to get it work. Regards

Comment: Thank a lot for quick answer. But my Problem is, that i have this RFID ME USB DOngle and how ever, it runs just with these SDK. But i can´t try to code something because i get these Exeption which make no sense. When it´s possible, can somebody download the sdk an try to make a project which doesn't throw this exeption?

Comment: I just watched your second link and the SDK cost around $750, you should get support for that price!

Comment: There is also a free SDK. You can download ...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d91er4ximefa9ya/X07MYdTkSJ/RFID%20ME%20SDK here is the free sdk

Comment: Hey Lucky guy, the SDK's father just replayed you!

Comment: Yeah it´s great! But strange is, that i found almost nothing on web from other Users ...?! So i hope that Kevin would help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the person that wrote the SDK. The problem you received is due how I was doing the expiration on the demo. You are seeing the error because of date format incompatibilities. I have changed that (and the problem should have gone away) and trying to get a few last bugs fixed before releasing the latest version. I hope to have that ready by the ending of the month.

If you are just trying to read tags, that works ok for the RFID ME USB Dongle. If you need to write to the tags, I am still trying to fix that (I reciently changed how the USB HID interface works and that has broken something).

Comment: Hey Kevin, thank you very much for this answer. THe GUI is great for testing Tags and read them out and write something on the tags !!! I´ll write you an email :)